# How can I parse a .ini file using php?

Tags: php, configuration, ini

I've joined to a new team/project and there is a `.ini` file in the project which is used as the project configuration file. The content of it looks like:

```
[version]
v                       =  1

[paths]
website                 =  http://localhost
base_url                =  /myweb/
images_path             =  C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myweb\\img\\
attached_file_path      =  C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\myweb\\attached_files\\

[limitation values]
max_avatar_size         =  2  ; MB
max_uploaded_image_size =  3  ; MB
max_uploaded_file_size  =  4  ; MB
```

I can access those values like this: `config('item_name')`, i.e `config('base_url')` which return `/myweb/`. Noted that `config()` function uses `parse_ini_file()` function.

My question is, what are those section titles? i.e `[version]`, `[paths]` .. ? Are they accessible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/parse_ini_file) have a second argument : `bool process_sections`.

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("sample.ini", true); // true means "process_sections"
// var_dump(array_keys($ini_array)) ;
var_dump($ini_array['paths']['base_url']) ;
```